# Merging of files with new name everytime

Tags: c#, file-io

I have been given task of merging two text files of  a folder say 'A' to another file in folder say 'B' and when we add more files to folder A then we get another merged file in folder B which contain only the data of files added to folder A after first merging.

I have tried this...

```
string[] Documents = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\vikas12");
string text = File.ReadAllText(Documents[0]);
int count = 1;
while (count < Documents.Length)
    text += File.ReadAllText(Documents[count++]);

StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\vikas13\vikas1.txt");

strw.WriteLine(text);
//foreach (var item in text)
//{
//    Console.Write(item);
//}

strw.Close();

string[] process = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\vikas12");
StreamWriter sm=new StreamWriter(@"D:\vikas13\processlog.txt");

foreach (var item in process)
{               
    sm.WriteLine(item);
}
sm.Close();
```

but I can not get the file with another name when added more files to input folder.

Comment: Ok, lets say you have files A.txt and B.txt in the folder vikas12 and you need to merge them to the folder vikas13 and name it vikas1.txt, right? Then whenever there are more than one file in the folder vikas12, you run the application and it takes all the files and merge them to a new file in the folder vikas13. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about naming a new file in folder "B" whenever new files are added then, you have couple of options

- You Could use GUID

  ```
  Guid g = new Guid();
  ```

Guid generates a new and unique id when instantiated.

- You can encrypt the names of the first two files using algorithms SHA or MD5 and use it to name the file in folder B